# Searching for number of values in one table, resizing number of rows in another table

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to search for the number of times "Commodity" appears in the table column: Securities[Strategy]. I then want to take that number and resize a table (named: Commodity) on another worksheet accordingly. If it appears 6 times in column Securities[Strategy], the Commodity table should resize to 6 rows, and so on for any number.

I'm very new to VBA. When I run the following code nothing happens.

```
Sub AdjRow()

    Dim Count1 As Integer
    Count1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Securities[Strategy]"), "Commodity")
    Count1 = Count1 + 12

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Commodity").Resize Range("$A$12:$J$" & Count1)

End Sub
```

Comment: are you sure that `Count1` returns anything above zero?

Comment: I checked when debugging. Count1 was pulling in the right number. I'm too new to understand it, but I think using ActiveSheet instead of referring to to the correct sheet, was preventing the macro from doing anything. I seem to remember trying to use WorkSheets("SheetName").ListObjects...(etc) - but that didn't work either. I ended up assigning the sheet and table to a variable (Var), as Eirik noted below, and then using Var.Resize Range... - as the command.

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help with debugging you can either print key values to the immediate window using `Debug.Print` or to a messagebox using `MsgBox`. In this case though, I am curious if you get any error messages when you attempt to run the macro. Editing your code and attempting to run it, it runs fine when the result I get from the `CountIf` is larger than one, but aborts with an error when it is one or less. If the table you attempt to resize don't have headers, I assume the macro will run fine if `CountIf` is greater than zero.

Here is the the code, sample data, and output I got when attempting to debug your code. I ran the code 3 times, and had return values of 8, 1, and 2 from the `CountIf`-function. Note how I didn't get the third address for the listobject on the second run-through, this was because the code aborted when it tried to set the `ListObject` to only its headers (`A2:J2`).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub AdjRow()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lo As ListObject

    Set r = Sheet2.Range("Securities[Strategy]")
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, "Test1")
    i = i + 1
    Set lo = Sheet1.ListObjects("Commodity")

    Debug.Print i
    Debug.Print r.Address
    Debug.Print lo.Range.Address

    lo.Resize Range("$A$2:$J$" & i)

    Debug.Print lo.Range.Address

End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

**Output to immediate window**

> 9 
>   $A$2:$A$10 
>   $A$2:$J$9 
>   $A$2:$J$9 
>    2  
>   $A$2:$A$10 
>   $A$2:$J$9 
>    3  
>   $A$2:$A$11 
>   $A$2:$J$9 
>   $A$2:$J$3

Comment: Thanks Eirik - very helpful. I'm very new to macros, but I think the problem may have been my use of "ActiveSheet" above. I don't think this command was doing anything. I got to point where I could click run; and, nothing would happen. I would debug in VB, and I could tell the range countif was working. It just wouldn't resize the table.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to get the new row's formatting to match the rest of the table.The new rows show up with different formatting.

Comment: I think it may also have been the use of "Integer" as my counting variable("i" above), instead of "Long"

Comment: @Tyler Using integer instead of long shouldn't affect anything, except that [using long is marginally more effficient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/4497791).